# Get a variable out of a try

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

I have a problem using a variable surrounded with a try :
Here's the beginning of my method :

```
public static word[] countWords(String text) {
    try {
            text = Preprocesseur.preprocess(text);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error méthod countWords");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Actually i need to use the String text (preprocessed) several line after, but java doesn't affect the value Preprocesseur.preprocess(text) to the whole method --> it stays in the try/catch block

I was wondering : how to call my method Preprocesseur.preprocess and affect its return String to the whole countWords method ?
Because a try/catch block is required (or throws declaration which leads to the same result)

Comment: Very quick thought:   public class MyPreprocesseurException extends IOException { public String getTextInProgress() {} }

Does that make sense?

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: Your method doesn't return a string, it returns a `word[]`.

Comment: Add all lines you need to the try/catch- block.

Comment: Tis somewhat of an anti-pattern to reassign method arguments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply switch from catching exceptions to throwing them higher form your method and deal with your problems later, like this:

```
public static word[] countWords(String text) throws IOException {
        text = Preprocesseur.preprocess(text);
}
```